# How to check what suppee patches have been installed on Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, security, patches

I'm about to start working on a Magento website and with the two security patches released yesterday (SUPEE-7405 & SUPEE-7616) I would like to ensure that all other security patches were installed before attempting them.

I can see from magereport.com that SUPEE 6788 (secrets leak) is not installed but 5344 (Shoplift), 5994 (admin disclosure), 6285 (XSS, RSS), 6482 (XSS) are all installed.

Magereport.com does not confirm if SUPEE-6285 or any of the patches prior to SUPEE-5344.

Is there any way to check on Magento exactly what patches have been installed? in the code or db perhaps?

Comment: Do you have an app/etc/applied.patches.list file on your Magento install ? This is a file that's automatically created when applying a patch and it should list which patches have been installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When patches are applied a file named `applied.patches.list` is added in the `app/etc/` directory.

```
app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

Next to that the patch is nothing more than a diff file so you can see what it should change when you open it and check in the targeted file if it is indeed changed.

Or

http://www.magereport.com

**UPDATE for 8788**

[Patch SUPEE-8788, MageReport.com says no, but I say yes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141447/patch-supee-8788-magereport-com-says-no-but-i-say-yes)

Comment: You can also check for security issues and applied patches at https://www.magereport.com/

Comment: magereport wont show you patches installed 100%, you have to check your files yourself

Comment: @Klettseb strangly 5344 patch is not in `app/etc/applied.patches.lis` although magereport.com says it's installed

Comment: there is any script to find out which patch install in our site if  app/etc/applied.patches.list is not there