# Patch SUPEE-8788, MageReport.com says no, but I say yes

Tags: magento-1, patches, supee-8788

I recently went with all the workarounds that Magento supplied after the v1 of the patch had some issues, and now have finally successfully installed v2 of SUPEE-8788.

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

As well as being listed in the `applied.patches.list`.

However when scanning through [magereport.com](http://magereport.com) to assure everything is working correctly, it still alerts me stating that I am unpatched for 8788. Should I just bypass this as a possible error on their side or could there still be something more I need to do?

Comment: Hi! Please see possible causes (Cloudflare or other caches) at https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-patch-supee-8788-release-1-9-3/ If you still feel the report is wrong, could you please submit your URL to code@magereport.com ? Thanks a lot for improving Magereport!

Comment: @willem I have checked and confirmed all the listed ways it checks, so I will send in the URL. Appreciate the help, love MageReport, thats why I need to see that green! :)

Answer (score 4):

**How Magereport detects the patch**

> Magereport checks for the following static assets that should have been removed:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

> It also checks for the following files that have been modified:

```
/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js should contain "fustyFlowFactory"
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css should contain "background:url(images/blank.gif) repeat;"
```

> **If you get an unexpected result**
>
> **Are you running multiple Magento installations on the same domain?** Due to the way Magento routing works, MageReport cannot distinguish between multiple installations on the same domain. So if you want to test an upgrade, you could put it on its own domain (eg. test.yourdomain.com).

**Log on to SSH (shell)**

> Every check that’s been installed can easily be found in the content of your shop. More specifically it’s logged in **app/etc/applied.patches.list**.
>
> So you run this command **'grep'** via SSH to access the list of applied security patches:

```
grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

> Hope It's helpful for any one.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be happening very often so here's the definite answer.

For the SUPEE-8788 patch, [MageReport test works like this](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-patch-supee-8788-release-1-9-3/):

> It checks for the following static assets that should have been
>   removed:
>
> ```
> /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
> /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
> /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
> ```
>
> It also checks for the following files that have been modified:
>
> - `/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js` should contain `"fustyFlowFactory"`
> - `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css` should contain `"background:url(images/blank.gif) repeat;"`

So here are the possibilites in your case:

- One of the `.swf` file has not been deleted when you ran the patch
- The patch did not apply properly on the `/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js` or the `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css`

Comment: so is the answer here to delete the files in `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/` manually? I did that to test and I passed in magereport. When I put files back on there, it failed.

Comment: @frshjb373 yes that's what the patch is supposed to do

Answer (score 1):

I too had something similar to this happened to me, this is what I ended up doing:

1. If you have the compiler enabled, recompile. The old code will be trapped in the include system until this is done.
2. Completely flush the cache so it reloads the refreshed code.

I was running on an Enterprise edition, not sure what you're on but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all files listed in files-to-delete.txt  comes with 8788 Patch., otherwise magereport will not detect this patch

files-to-delete.txt

```
 skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
 skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
 skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

Note : Do not rename files , delete it